What is the short cut key for ''Object Menu'' under Object Mode
I can not find the short cut key for this menu, but I would like access to it.
I have checked the section under the properties key map but can not locate the options to assign a short cut key.
Is there a way to assign a short cut key to this? The python script I believe is VIEW3D_MT_object.
I have never used python, and adding this into the short cut key does not execute.
Thank you.

In version 4.2 adding a shortcut key works for me. Did you right click on Object to get the add shortcut option?

No, I feel like my right click button actually does not do anything, maybe i have removed what it does, can you let me know what your rich mouse click is assigned to please so I can investigate this further?

It's hard-coded AFAIK and doesn't even depend on whether you use right or left click for selection. Maybe try to reset your keymap in the preferences, but if you can't see a contextual menu when you RMB the menu, then maybe you should report it as a bug.

I will upgrade to 4.2. I am on 4.0. I love updates on this.
